# Antlr4 Testrig runs but I get no output

Tags: antlr4

I am new to `ANTLR4`. I followed the installation instruction on github and ran the example successfully. So installation appears to be OK. Next I downloaded a grammer file I wish to use, ran `antlr4` on it, and compiled the resultant files with `javac`. Then I tried an example like this:

```
C:> grun GrammerName tokens examplefile
```

This runs for a couple of seconds and returns, but there is no response. Ive tried using `-tree` and `-ps` but I get nothing with either. If I supply a bad filename, then I get a stream of file-not-found error messages, so it is doing something... but if I supply a random data file, I also get no response. Which suggests to me that my example file is not being seen as a valid example of the grammer in question. But why do I not get an error message?

In essence, my question is how do I get TestRig to supply some feedback about the example file I've supplied?

I've tried reading the manual pages on the `antlr.org` site but there's too much terminology I'm not familiar with yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you supply `tokens` as the name of the start rule, that tells `grun` to not invoke the parser at all and only run the tokenizer. This is generally only useful in combination with the `-tokens` flag, which prints the tokens. Otherwise the only output you see would be possible tokenization errors.

The options `-tree`, `-ps` or `-gui` display the result of the parser. So if the parser isn't executed, they do nothing at all.

If you want to see the parse tree, you should replace `tokens` with the name of the rule that you want to use. If you want to see the list of generated tokens, you should add the `-tokens` flag.

> Which suggests to me that my example file is not being seen as a valid example of the grammer in question.

It's the opposite actually. If `grun` detects errors, it will print them to the console. So if there is no output, `grun` did not detect any errors (however when using `tokens`, it will only look for lexical errors, not syntactical ones). When calling `grun` with valid input and without flags such as `-tree` or `-tokens`, the expected result would be that there's no output.

Comment: Thanks for the answer -- it has helped -- but I'm still not clear on what TestRig has actually done. I will soon be developing an application (and I've ordered the ANTLR4 book to that end) but in the meantime, I just want to see if some example files are correct. That is, I have a grammer (successfully compiled) and I have some example files supposedly written in the language defined in the grammer. Is it possible to use TestRig to see if these example files are valid or not?

Comment: @milesago Yes, as I said, if you provide a rule name other than `tokens`, `grun` will produce error messages if the input does not match that rule or no output otherwise. So if you run `grun GrammarName program examplefile` and get no error messages, the file is syntactically valid.

Comment: (Assuming `program` is a rule defined in the grammar meant to match whole programs)